# Laptop Upgrade Guide [Lenovo G560]

Tags: cpu, lenovo-laptop

I want to ask if I could upgrade my current CPU with another one. My laptop with is Lenovo G560

Here is the current CPU

Intel Core i3 370M

2.40 GHz
 / 3MB Cache
 / TDP 35 W

I would like to know if I could swat it with this one

Intel Core i7 640M

2.80 GHz (Turbo boost to 3.46 GHz)
 / 4MB Cache
 / TDP 35 W

Both of them are Sandy Bridge architecture 
Both of them have the same Max TDP of 35 W
Both of them fit in a rPGA Socket
Both of them have the same size

Any Ideas?
Tell me if you want more information.

Comment: If both are the same socket, and are not soldered, then you should be able to replace the CPU in question.  But you won't really get any performance boost with only a 0.40 Ghz increase.

Comment: About the performance but what if turbo boost is on? And second, are there any motherboard limitations?

Comment: Any performance boosts from turbo boost would be limited.  Its not something that is left on.  It also means your laptop would generate more heat.  Its very likely the additional heat would actually cause the CPU to downclock instead.